# How to tell which row to chose if there are duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have a table below.

[image]

The Check column has a formula: `=IF(AND(COUNTIF([Item],[@Item])=2,[Type]="123"),1,0)`.
What it does is if there are duplicates in the Item column, AND if the Type column is 123, it returns 1, else 0.

I want to extract values from the Price column. However sometimes data has duplicates, and I want to get a value with Type=123 (the Red rectangle).

I created the Check column to flag which row to select, and I tried to add it as a condition.
But I do not want to use Power Query for this, and use only formulas.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without check column. Try-

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Item],[@Item])>1,INDEX([Price],MATCH(1,([Item]=[@Item])*([Type]=123),0)),INDEX([Price],MATCH([@Item],[Item],0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but I get #N/A for both of ItemA. I do not get what the `INDEX([Price],MATCH(1,([Item]=[@Item])*([Type]=123),0))` part does. It has `1` and also `*` in the Match function. What do they do? Would you please elaborate it?

Comment: @P002143_k Equality statements return either `TRUE` or `FALSE` Boolean values. When math operations are applied to these then they return a 1 when `TRUE` or a 0 when `FALSE`. Multiplication equates to an `AND` statement, addition equates to `OR`. When both equalities are `TRUE`,  `([Item]=[@Item])*([Type]=123)` becomes `TRUE * TRUE`, which equals 1.

Comment: @bugdrown I tried disassembling the formula, and found that `MATCH(1,([Item]=[@Item])*([Type]=123),0)` gets #N/A. I still do not get what the 1 in the Match formula does. Why does it in the Match formula??

Comment: @P002143_k The 1 is what the formula is trying to match in the 2nd part of the formula. If you highlight the 2nd part of the formula and press the F9 key, you should see an array of 1's and 0's. Press ESC key when done looking at the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, replace `Table5` with your table name in the following:

```
=FILTER(Table5,(Table5[Type]=123)*(Table5[Check]=1),"")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my excel is not Office 365. but thank you very much for your help.